# How to set system property for Gradle Daemon

Tags: gradle, jvm-arguments, system-properties, gradle-daemon

I would like to set a JVM system property for the Gradle daemon process.

I tried the following in `~/.gradle/gradle.properties`:

```
org.gradle.daemon=true
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
```

It seems org.gradle.jvmargs mentioned [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html) does only take effect for certain options, e.g. `-Xmx` takes effect in the daemon. The [daemon-doc](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/gradle_daemon.html) does not really go into detail about this as well.

What is the best way to get the gradle daemon started with a specific system property?